# How to reduce application size when it is installed in sd card

Tags: sd-card, internal, apk

I have recently started developing a simple application which has a very few KB (less than 20KB) of resources most of which are png images. I have written on the application manifest that the application should prefer external storage.

The problem is that the application size is reduced only from 680KB to 500KB. I have seen games that reduce their application size from 10MB to 200KB when moved to sd card. Since my phone has only 70MB of internal storage available when nothing is intalled from google play it seems stupid for an application that has a single activity with some buttons and textboxes and 2 32X32 png files to take 0.5 MB of data.

What should I do while developing the application to make it move most of it on the sd card? I am not really concerned about the apk file size but on the remaining data on the internal storage, since it is fairly cheap to buy a 4GB sd card than a newer phone with larger internal memory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like there is a tool designed just for that purpose and google recommends developers to use it. Its called [proguard](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/proguard.html). It does wonders to the application size.